# ng-View não renderiza o conteudo - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quando acesso meu index.php, peço nas configuração de rotas do meu Angular que ele chame a view "index.php" dentro da pastar "view", porem ele acha mas não renderiza nada na minha tela

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
 $routeProvider
  .when('/',{
   templateUrl: 'view/index.php',
   controller:'search'
   
  }).otherwise({redirectTo:"/"})

    //Se descomentar tbm não funciona
 //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Teste</a>

   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>

 <div ng-view>
  
 </div>

 <script src="/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="/angularapp/setup/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/angularapp/setup/angular.min.js.map"></script>
 <script src="/angularapp/setup/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/angularapp/setup/angular-route.min.js.map"></script>
 
 <script src="/angularapp/config.js"></script>
 <script src="/angularapp/controllers/search.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

então! quase certeza que é a falta da chamada da controller: que você definiu ai.

```
<div ng-controller="search" ng-view>
ou
<div ng-controller="search">
   <div ng-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso não é necessário. O controller será instanciado no momento que a view renderizar a página.

Comment: Fala Luiz, obrigado pela atenção, mas avisa sido bobeira minha, eu tinha invertido o nome de um controller nas configs, ja arrumei! 

Vlw